# Cartesian equation of the plane $\sigma$ through three points and orthogonal to the plane $\pi$

Tags: geometry

I'm in trouble... I have to find the cartesian equation of the plane $\sigma$ through three points and orthogonal to another plane $\pi$... How can I solve this?

Comment: I think it is impossible if the 3 points are arbitrary.

Comment: Hi! Can you add more context to your question? For example, how is the plane $\pi$ assigned?...

Comment: @MattAllegro let be $\pi$ in vectorial form... I haven't got any data

Comment: @MattAllegro for example, if I have to find $\sigma$ through $A=(2,4,4)$ and $B=(2,-2,-4)$ and orthogonal to $\pi:4y-3z-4=0$, the plane is $x-2=0$... but, if I have three points instead of two?

Comment: I'm supposing that if for the case before mentioned I have to calculate the vector $AB=(0,-6,-8)$, then for three points (let have another point $C=(1,3,0)$) I have to calculate the vector $ABC=(1,9,8)$? Is this right?

Comment: $ABC$ is not a vector. You can calculate $AC$ or $BC$, but they might not end up in the same plane if $C$ is arbitrary.

Comment: and so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Three points already define a plane. If that plane is not perpendicular to the other plane, there is nothing you can do.